# Why do we need a "receiver" class in the Command design pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am learning command design pattern. As far as I know, four terms always associated with the command pattern are command, receiver, invoker and client.

A concrete command class has an `execute()` method and the invoker has a couple of commands. The invoker decides when to call the `execute()` method of a command.

When the `execute()` method is called, it calls a method of the receiver. Then, the receiver does the work.

I don't understand why do we need the receiver class? We can do the work inside `execute()` method, it seems that the receiver class is redundant.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Design patterns are used to solve software problems.

You have to understand the problem before trying to understand the solution (in this case Command pattern)

The problems which command pattern apply are in the context of an object A (client) invoking a method in an object B (receiver), so the Receiver is part of the problem, not part of the solution.

The solution or idea that command pattern offers  is to encapsulate  the method invocation from A to B  in an object (Command), in fact this is close to the formal pattern definition. When you manage a request as an object you are able to solve some problems or to implement some features. (you also will need other pieces like the one called Invoker)

This [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) can give you some good examples of what kind of problems o features are suitable for command pattern.

note: Comamnd pattern is not necesary about decoupling, in fact the most common example pattern immplementation, the client needs to make a new instance of the receiver so we cannot talk about decoupling here.

Comment: The command pattern is used in [JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm), there is no receiver in this case. We always put our testing code in the concrete command class.

Comment: I 've seen an old-fashioned way implementation called [EJBCommand](http://books.google.com.uy/books/about/EJB_design_patterns.html?id=hpFdoX2ICckC&redir_esc=y) in which you can see business logic within the Command class as you mentioned, however in this case the logic executes in the server's side so the Receiver is (according to my interpretation) the server's component that executes the logic allocated in the command. May be you scenario is smiliar to this.

Comment: except client =/= invoker ,so it is about decoupling the invoker and the reciever.

Answer (score 8):

Imagine a class that can do couple of things, like Duck, it can eat and quack. Duck is a receiver in this example. To apply command pattern here, you need to be able to wrap eating and quacking into a command. They should be separate classes that derive from Command base class with `execute()` method because Duck can have only single `execute()` method. So `EatCommand.execute()` calls `Duck.eat()` and `QuackCommand.execute()` calls `Duck.quack()`.

Comment: Great answer Andy, just what I was looking for.

Comment: why not call `duck.eat()` directly instead of calling it through a command?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta: for various application specific reasons. for example, you'd like to call `duck.eat()` and other methods in another thread. you can have a queue of commands, populate it from one thread and execute in another. different methods can take different number of arguments, and these arguments are provided by calling thread and stored in Command, then on executing thread you have a nice list of commands and all you need to do is to call their `Execute` one by one

Comment: In all the example I've seen yet, a command is doing nothing but calling the receiver's method. There are no extra parameters being passed. Invoker is responsible for how and when it has to be called whether it is a queue or other thread. So I'm not understanding the need of command.

Comment: What about if the 'receiver' is just a model, say it models a github repository and holds all meta data, and to build a stack of commands like create, delete, add webhook etc. To me it would make more sense to include the logic to create or delete a repo in the command and give the command the model rather than add all this functionality to the repository object.

Answer (score 7):

The goal of the **command pattern** is to decouple the invoker from the receiver.

The receiver must do the work ,not the command itself , the command just knows what is the receiver method to call, or the command can execute other commands . With the command pattern  the invoker doesnt know what is being called expect for the command.

So a command can be reused by many invokers to execute the same action on the receiver.

Comment: The command pattern is used in [JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm), there is no receiver in this case. We always put our testing code in the concrete command class.

Comment: well , i dont know how junit is coded so i dont have answer for that.I'm just telling you what is the definition of the command pattern and what the receiver is in that context.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is depends. This is not based on my opinion alone. From GOF, Command Pattern, Implementation (page 238)

"How intelligent should a command be? A command can have a wide range of abilities. At one extreme it merely defines a binding between a receiver and the actions that carry out the request. At the other extreme it implements everything itself without delegating to a receiver at all. The latter extreme is useful when you want to define commands that are independent of existing classes, when no suitable receiver exists, or when a command knows its receiver implicitly. For example, a command that creates another application window may be just as capable of creating the window as any other object."

So I do not think one should create a receiver class just for the sake of it, or because most example say so. Create it only if there is a real need. One such case is when a class that acts as a receiver already exists as a separate class. If you have to write the code that is going to be invoked/executed and see no reason to create a separate class for that, then I do not see any fault in adding the invoker code to Command itself.